# Ubuntu AWS Workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

We've been toying with switching to cloud based desktops, specifically AWS Workspace. Is there support for Ubuntu desktops though? To this point I've only been able to generate Windows environments.

*UPDATE: Amazon Workspaces now supports Amazon Linux 2, an offshoot of CentOS.*

Comment: Just as an update, AWS Workspaces just launched Ubuntu Desktop as another option: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-workspaces-introduces-ubuntu-desktops/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:  Workspaces now have a linux option, in case anyone finds this.

<strike>AWS Workspaces only supports Windows at the moment.</strike>

From the [product description](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/):

> Amazon WorkSpaces is a managed, secure cloud desktop service. You can use Amazon WorkSpaces to provision either Windows or Linux desktops

Comment: Could you post a source? Those are my findings as well, but an official source would make this best answer :)

Comment: This is no longer the case, there are two versions of Windows and a version of Linux available. I have added an answer, below.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, when Amazon says "Linux Desktop" they specifically mean "Amazon Linux Desktop" there's no other Linux distribution available as far as I can tell

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Workspaces now allows the use of Windows 7 and Windows 10, as well as Amazon Linux 2. There are options that are eligible for the Free Tier.

Descriptions of what software you can install are available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/faqs/#Bundles_and_Custom_Images).